# Facebook Pages API Post Without User Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a FB App to publish posts as page from another site.

Many of the users will be publishing on my page, so I'm trying to create a function without user login or session.

I'm now doing it via creating Page Access Token manually from Graph API Explorer and injecting it into the code.

If I could create the access token in the code without user login, it will be my solution.

Is it possible or anyone knows how to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: In case anyone wonder my code, it is below.

```
    $config['appId'] = $appId;
    $config['secret'] = $secret;

    $fb = new \Facebook($config);

    $message = array(
        'access_token' => $page_access_token, //manually injected
    );

    $message['message'] = 'message';

    $message['link'] = 'link';

    $posturl = '/'.$page_id.'/feed';
    $result = $fb->api($posturl,'POST',$message);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is example code in the docs, this is how to post stuff with a specific Access Token:

```
$response = $fb->post('/{page-id}/feed', $data, '{access-token}');
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_post_links

Of course you can´t create a Page Token without user login, that would be weird. You can only create a Page Token with a User Token, and you can only get a User Token with login. Extended Page Tokens are valid forever, so you only need to create it once and just store it.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My post function is working, I only need the function for getting token and I asked if I can get it without user login. If it is not possible, I want to embed a page admin's login information into the code, log it in, get token, post as page, log it out.

Comment: you can´t do that. you only get a token on explicit user interaction, and you should NEVER embed login data.

Comment: not sure why you would want to do that anyway, just create a login process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login - then get an extended page token and store it.

Comment: Because I want to create an app where the content that members are posted to the site will be published on official FB page. My members don't have publishing permissions on the page.

Comment: so you want every other user to be able to post "as page"? you should not do that...

Comment: This is why I want to post without user interaction. I will be controlling what they are posting in my function. After that, if the content is approved, I will post it on the page, as page. If I do it with user login, I have to give every user a role for the page.

Comment: ok, then just create an extended page token and store it. you need it one time only, it is valid forever. check out the links in my answer, everything you need to know is in there.

Comment: Thank you luschn, it is a possible solution. But Facebook says;

"Page Access tokens have expirations; your app can continue to use a Page Access token for an hour after you originally get it.

If your app makes multiple requests to a node, the initial request gets a token and subsequent requests may get new tokens. The initial token will continue working as long as it is not expired.

If your all of your app's Page tokens expire, you should request a new one."

Comment: i said "extended page token". those are valid forever. just try it.